# error: request for member size in ... which is of non-class type char

Tags: c++

I'm not very good at programming, nor experienced, and this is for a class where the teacher is of negligible aid.

The title is the error I'm getting.  This is the function:

```
void CapFormat (string Names, int NameCount)
 {
   int Comma;
   int c;
   int d;

    string::size_type len;

   for(c = 0; c < NameCount; c ++)
   {
     len = static_cast<unsigned> (Names[c].size);  //error starts here
     for(d = len; d > 0; d --)
     {
       tolower((Names[c].at(d)));  //supposed to lower cases every letter
     }
     touppper(Names[c].at(0));  //supposed to upper case first letter
     Comma = Names[c].find(",");  //supposed to find a comma between last and first names
     Comma = Comma + 1;
     toupper(Names[c].at(Comma));  //Error here as well.  supposed to then upper case letter after the comma.
   }
 }
```

Here is the expanded version of the errors:

```
In function âvoid CapFormat(std::string, int)â:
error: request for member âsizeâ in âNames.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((long unsigned int)c))â, which is of non-class type âcharâ
error: request for member âatâ in âNames.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((long unsigned int)c))â, which is of non-class type âcharâ
error: request for member âatâ in âNames.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = error: âtouppperâ was not declared in this scope
error: request for member âfindâ in âNames.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((long unsigned int)c))â, which is of non-class type âcharâ
error: request for member âatâ in âNames.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((long unsigned int)c))â, which is of non-class type âcharâ
```

Cstring, cctype, and string are all included.  I've copied the syntax directly from my book, everything should be in order, but the errors remain.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the way you use the `Names` parameter in your code suggest that it is supposed to be an array. But you declared it as a single object. Hence the errors.

The parameter was apparently supposed to be declared as either

```
void CapFormat (string Names[], int NameCount)
```

or

```
void CapFormat (string *Names, int NameCount)
```

(which is the same thing.) Compare this to your book. It is either your mistake or an error in the book.

Secondly, the `size` line is supposed to look as

```
len = static_cast<unsigned>(Names[c].size());
```

(note the extra `()`). And there's absolutely no need for that `static_cast` to `unsigned` there. Just do

```
len = Names[c].size();
```

Was this `static_cast` your idea? If it is in the book, that would be a rather strange book.

The illogical mix of inappropriate `int` variables and proper `string::size_type` variables makes me doubt that this was actually taken from a book.

Comment: Yes it was taken straight from the book.  And yes it is rather strange.  Your advice fixed the errors I pointed out right away, in direct contradiction to what the book says should work.  thank you very much.

Comment: @LawrenceBenecke A book that is wrong, a teacher who's no help, you've got it tough. At least SO is here.

Comment: Another error `tolower((Names[c].at(d)))` should be `Names[c].at(d) = tolower(Names[c].at(d));`. tolower and toupper are functions which return the lower case or upper case version of a character. You then have to do something with that returned character, like assign it back to a string. Did your book get this wrong as well?

Comment: @LawrenceBenecke You should probably accept/upvote AndreyT's answer